# Find head noun, "he himself"

Tags: syntax, parsing, nouns, pronouns

I have run into a problem when I am trying to find the head noun for a NP in this sentence. I haven't been able to find any rules explaining why one of them would be head, or if they even belong in the same NP. The two words in *italics* are the words that I am wondering about.

> Oscar took the corn, so that *he himself* could enjoy the corn.

The task that I am doing is trying to find each free-standing NP in a text, and analyze those NPs. This one is confusing me, and the parser that I am using ([Enju 2.4 online demo](http://www.nactem.ac.uk/enju/demo.html)) is not helping me me find the head.

I am actually analyzing *Oscar himself* (produced by a learner of English), however, this isn't really grammatically correct, so I've changed the wording here.

I would be thankful for any of your thoughts, help, or ideas on this subject.

Comment: "He himself" is an NP with "he" as head. The reflexive "himself" is just an optional modifier in the NP, used to emphasise that it was "he" who could enjoy the corn and possibly no one else.

Comment: Modifiers tend to occur next to what they modify, but *himself* in your example can be moved away from *he*, so I doubt it modifies *he*.  I suggest you pay no attention to proposals about structure unless evidence is offered.  @Billj gives no evidence.

Comment: @Greg Lee Now that is an absurd message, both rude and of no help to the OP, who has already responded. What else could "himself" modify? This is a very simple matter.

Comment: I'm not sure if _himself_ should still be considered as modifying _he_ if it were moved away. There seems to be a difference. To me as an L2 speaker, at least,  _He himself could enjoy the corn_ could be paraphrased as 'It was he, and not anyone else, who could enjoy the corn' , whereas 'He could enjoy the corn' could be paraphrased as 'He could enjoy the corn on his own'. I'm not a native speaker though, so I may be wrong... In any case, since the sentence is still okay without _he_ but not without _himself_, I think _he_ is the more likely head.

Comment: Yes, reflexives can occur in several positions. If for example the reflexive is located at the end of a clause as in _Ed is a teacher himself_, the reflexive is a clause adjunct with "Ed" as antecedent, not a modifier in the NP headed by "teacher". But that is not what the OP asked about. The focus here is on their example, which contained a reflexive pronoun in modifier function in an NP headed by "he".

Comment: What's the test for "in modifier function"? As Greg points out, the reflexive can appear elsewhere but not just anywhere, so there is a rule involved that doesn't apply to most modifiers.

Answer (score 1):

In my view, there is a very simple argument you can deploy to justify the claim that in *He himself* the head is *he*, not *himself* (assuming *he himself* is a single NP/DP constituent, which is a possible analysis, but not necessarily the right or only one, since *himself* need not appear next to *he*): if the contrary were true, the whole NP/DP would **inherit** the grammatical properties of *himself*, rather than those of *he*, would **not** carry nominative Case, and therefore could not be a legitimate subject of a finite clause like *...he himself could enjoy the corn.* Furthermore, if *himself* were the head, *he* would have to be an optional 'adjunct' (note that it cannot be a complement, since *himself* is saturated), and, since optional adjuncts, by definition, need not be present, *himself* could by himself act as a DP/NP in subject position. Apart from the case issue that would raise, it would follow that an anaphor need **not** have a binding antecedent c-commanding it in the smallest clause that contains the reflexive, which, of course, violates Principle A of Binding Theory.

As you can see, there are at least **two** rather solid arguments in support of the standard view that only *he* can be the head of the construction *he himself* (if it really is a 'construction' - a constituent, say at surface level - and has to be analysed as a single NP/DP). In case, however, you should remain skeptical and ask "How do you know that *himself* is **not** nominative?", the answer would be straightforward: if it were, * ***Himself*** could enjoy the corn should be a mere violation of Principle A of Binding Theory and ***Him*** could enjoy the corn should be a possible English sentence, but, of course, it is not. Finally, if you were to ask me, "How, come, can *himself* carry accusative case at all if there is neither a preposition nor a verb governing it whether it follows *he* or appears clause finally?", I can contemplate two possible answers: a), perhaps the most plausible one, that there is a **hidden** preposition (*by*, or maybe *for*?) (cf. *He did it **himself*** < *He did it **by** himself*), as there arguably is in cases like *I saw her **Saturday/last weekend***, or b) that accusative is the 'elsewhere', or 'default', case (since nominative and genitive are assigned only in very specific contexts, subject of a finite verb or specifier of a Determiner or a noun, depending on your preferences concerning NP structure, respectively), an approach that the existence of 'absolute accusatives' in Latin and other languages could arguably endorse.